# how to extract roles from access token in Angular-oauth2-oidc

Tags: angular-oauth2-oidc

I am using **angular-oauth2-oidc** lib for authentication. After successful authentication, I want to fetch roles/ other properties from the access token. But as of now, there is no direct method which can parse token and gives its internal attributes.
Is there any way via which can get all the roles or other attributes of the token? Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Depends on where you store roles. Often, the *access* token is just an opaque string; at least, to the library it is opaque. You might know it's JWT, if I recall correctly you'd need to parse that yourself using said library.

What *does* work is if it's (also) part of the *identity*. Calling `this.oauthService.getIdentityClaims()` should give you an object with wall the claims by key, for example roles could be part of it, depending on your server setup.